# Question about solving a quadratic a word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

> > The question is the sum of two positive number is $21$. Fifteen less than twice the square of the smaller number gives the larger number. If $x$ represents the smaller number, write a system of equations to model this information and solve the system to determine the two positive numbers.

---

Here's my solution to the problem:

Let the smaller and larger number be $x$.

$$15 - 2 \sqrt  x = x
$$
$$x = 21$$ 
Then how do I solve it? Because I won't be able solve it then.

Comment: You need to read more carefully to define your equations. I find it helps to literally write down what each variable stands for.  You have two numbers mentioned in the text but only one variable in your equations, so something is wrong.  Let the variables be $x,y$ with $x \lt y$.  Note the use of $\lt$ instead of $\le$ is based on the fact that there is a smaller number.  We have $2x^2-15=y, x+y=21$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $x$ is the smaller number let the larger number be $y$.

Then we have following conditions:

> > $1.)$ Sum of numbers is $21$ hence  $$x+y=21\tag 1$$
> >
> > $2.)$
> >     $$2x^2-15=y\tag 2$$ 
> >     Now, substituting the value $y=21-x$ from $(1)$ into $(2)$, we get $$2x^2-15=21-x$$ 
> >     $$2x^2+x-36=0$$  $$2x^2+9x-8x-36=0$$  $$x(2x+9)-4(2x+9)=0$$  $$(2x+9)(x-4)=0$$
> >     $$x=4, \ \frac{-9}{2} $$ But the numbers are positive hence we get $x=\color{red}{4}$
> >
> > Then the corresponding values of $y$ 
> >     $$y=21-x=21-4=\color{red}{17}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $x+y=21$ and $2x^2-15=y$. Substitute the latter into the former, and we get $x+(2x^2-15)=21,$ or $2x^2+x-36=0.$ Can you work from there to solve for $x$?

Answer (score 0):

"Fifteen less than twice the square of the smaller number gives the larger number."

Key tips on translations:

- Two different numbers need two different variables (not $x$ for both).
- "Square" ($x^2$) is not the same as "square root" ($\sqrt{x}$).
- "Less than" reverses the order of the terms mentioned.

Therefore this second sentence is translated as: $2x^2 - 15 = y$, and the first sentence means $x + y = 21$. You should find this easier to solve. Recommend that you practice some translations from English to math, for example here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/introduction-to-algebra/writing-expressions-tutorial/e/writing_expressions_1